# How install python-pysocks in CentOS/oracle linux?

Tags: python, centos, urllib3, oraclelinux, pysocks

When I try to update using the command `sudo yum update` I get the error:

```
Error: Package: python2-urllib3-1.22-2.el7.noarch (ol7_developer)
           Requires: python-pysocks
```

so when I try to install the `python2-urllib3-1.22-2.el7.noarch.rpm` I get the error:

```
Error: Package: python2-urllib3-1.22-2.el7.noarch (/python2-urllib3-1.22-2.el7.noarch)
           Requires: python-pysocks
```

Then I tried to download the package https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/SRPMS/Packages/p/python-pysocks-1.6.8-7.el7.src.rpm but when I try to install: `sudo yum install /home/<USER>/python-pysocks-1.6.8-7.el7.src.rpm` I get the error:

```
Cannot add package /home/bigdata/python-pysocks-1.6.8-7.el7.src.rpm to transaction. Not a compatible architecture: src
```

How do I correct? Where should I download this package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python2-pysocks is in the EPEL repo on yum.oracle.com.

Try:

```
sudo yum install oracle-epel-release-el7
sudo yum update
```